# html source encode

Tags: php, html, decode, quotes

when I view source on my php page I get `&quot;` for a quote. But instead, I would like `"` to be used in the source code. I have no control over manually replacing it so Im wondering if there is a function to do such a thing.

Comment: Does the html page itself display correctly or all are quotes being printed as &quote;? What's wrong with seeing &quote in your source code since most html validators and the like require that duoble-quotes be printed as &quote; in the source code?

Comment: no bothering with source code.

Comment: The HTML displays correctly, but this isnt for display purposes, this is because im transferring data from a server to Second Life, and it comes out as &quot;

Comment: You see &quote;
in source code or 
in generated html in text editor or
in generated html in browser?
Please, be more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the PHP and want to change all html special characters to their rightful variations use:

```
print htmlspecialchars_decode($string);
```

Comment: I think this is the best way given what is being attempted here. +1

Answer (score 0):

You could do this very simply using `str_replace`.

```
$string = str_replace('&quot;', '"', $string);
```

However, as Levi said, why not just leave it this way? It should have no effect on the display.

Comment: I think the issue is due to the fact that he needs to take the source output and input into something else. The &quote; is causing the issue.